# Parse a log file and send info to sensu

Tags: parsing, logging, sensu

Is there a way to make a Sensu check that takes a .log file as input and parses it and returns selected info to InfluxDB.

Im very new to this so maybe I didnt describe my problem the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to do this is with Logstash (mostly because I use ELK for general log aggregation anyway).

Set up a Logstash server.
https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash

Install logstash-forwarder on the client(s). Configure logstash-forwarder to read the logs you want and to send them to your logstash server.
https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder

In the Logstash server's config;

Define a lumberjack input for the log you want to send to sensu (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-lumberjack.html).

Eg:
    input {

```
  lumberjack {
    port => 5555
    type => "logs"
    tags => ["lumberjack", "influxdb"]
  }
}
```

Do your processing/filtering.
Eg:

```
filter {
  if ("influxdb" in [tags]) {
      ...
  }
}
```

Define an InfluxDB output (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-influxdb.html).
Eg:

```
output {
  influxdb {
      ...
   }
}
```

This method would skip Sensu all together. If you do want to send the logs to Sensu and see the output in Uchiwa it would involve setting up some Sensu-friendly info in your logstash filter:

```
filter {
  if ("influxdb" in [tags]) {
      add_field => { "name" => "SensuCheckName" }
      add_field => { "handler" => "SensuHandlerName" }
      add_field => { "output" => "the stuff you want to send to sensu" }
      add_field => { "status" => "1" }
  }
}
```

And sending the logs to sensu's RabbitMQ transport (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-rabbitmq.html):

```
output {
  rabbitmq {
      exchange => "results"
      exchange_type => "direct"
      host => "192.168.0.5 or whatever it is"
      vhost => "/sensu"
      user => "sensuUser"
      password => "whateverItIs"
   }
}
```

Define a Sensu handler for this (name above in logstash filter) and do any extra processing there before passing it to InfluxDB.
If you haven't got Sensu sending data to InfuxBD set up already, go here: https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-influxdb